# Using Scala type aliases from Java code

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop, type-alias

Suppose I have type alias defined in scala as

```
object Foo {
  type Bar = Option[String]
}
```

It looks like I cannot refer to alias in Java code like that (it simply complains *cannot find symbol*):

```
import Foo.*;

public class Cafebabe {
  void bar(Bar x) {
  //...
  }
}
```

I've tried static import as well.

*(More specifically, I have java reflection code which I cannot change that needs to know parameter type and I need to feed Bar alias to it).*

I know, I can create wrapper in Scala

```
class BarWrapper(value: Bar)
```

but maybe I'm missing some other way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Type aliases are only visible to the Scala compiler, and like generic types they don't appear anywhere in the JVM class files.

If you're in Java, you're stuck using the unaliased type `Option[String]` since *javac* has no way of knowing about the type alias `Bar` that you declared in your Scala code. Wherever you would have used `Bar` just use `Option[String]` (which is `scala.Option<String>` in Java) and it should work fine.

Comment: Type aliases **have** to appear somewhere in JVM class files, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use aliases from other libraries.

But as far as I found they are scrambled in some "additional data" field in class definition.

Comment: @Keros - That's a good point, but by the same logic generic type signature information are also included in class files in some format. Whatever format they use when they compile type declarations, it's sadly not something that Java recognizes.