# Convert java.lang.String to Scala string

Tags: java, string, scala, scala-java-interop

I have a String in my Scala program that I'd like to cast as an Int.

```
def foo(): Int = x.getTheNumericString().toInt
```

The problem is that `x.getTheNumericString()` comes from a Java library and returns a `java.lang.String`, which doesn't have a `toInt` method.

I know I can create a Scala string with  `val s: String = "123"`, but I noticed that when I create a string like `val t = "456"` I get a `java.lang.String`.  [I have heard that Scala String is just a wrapper around java.lang.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559938/scala-string-vs-java-lang-string-type-inference), but I haven't found any clear documentation on how to cast to the Scala string.

Is there some function I can use like:

```
def foo(): Int = f(x.getTheNumericString()).toInt
```

As it stands now, my compiler complains about the original definition `value toInt is not a  member of String`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a wrapper, but actually java.lang.String. No need in additional hassle:

```
» touch 123
» scala
...

val foo = new java.io.File("123")
// java.io.File = 123

// Get name is a java api, which returns Java string

foo.getName.toInt
// res2: Int = 123
```

Comment: To back this up, check the source of Predef out: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.1/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L85

Comment: @gpampara this will require an additional comment, stating that `type` will be substituted at compile time and [leaves no actual traces in resulting bytecode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13673839/298389)

Comment: I wish that were true, but my compiler complains that `toInt is not a member of String`

Comment: @usmcs which version of Scala are you using?

Comment: 2.10.1 in Intellij 13.0.1

Comment: Try to compile it with SBT, it can happen that IDEA compiler misses things up like methods, the only source of truth for me is the Scala compiler when I'm in doubt.

Comment: I have the same result with SBT `myfile.scala:13 value toLong is not a member of String`

Comment: @usmcs [I set up basic project](https://gist.github.com/lazyval/90027f227114d48aa080), which makes use of scala 2.10.1 and java api, returning String. As it was expected it works just fine. There must be something else you're not saying us. You can check out that project by yourself by cloning it (git link is on the left) and running `sbt run` in it's directory

Comment: [Here is the IDEA result](http://take.ms/9hqrl). No compile errors, no runtime errors, no error highlighting. Sbt one looks essentially the same

Comment: @om-nom-nom The project works perfectly for me. I'll go back to my project and try to find out what is different.

Comment: I found it, there was a stray import of `scala.predef.String`. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`java.lang.String` is implicitly amended with Scala specific string methods so no manual conversion should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use asInstanceOf[String] to syntactically convert Java string to Scala string.

```
val str: String = "java_string".asInstanceOf[String]
```