# Call Scala Aux trait with type alias in Java

Tags: java, scala

I have this `Holder` object defined in Scala as follows:

```
trait Holder {
  type L
} 

object Holder {
  type Aux[L0] = Holder {type L = L0}
  }
```

The type in Scala for it would be `Holder.Aux[L]`. I would like to reference this type in Java, for example in a method call, but not sure what the syntax would be.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673839/using-scala-type-aliases-from-java-code

Comment: @LászlóvandenHoek It's not the same, see the `Aux` pattern.

Comment: Still the same answer; "Type aliases are only visible to the Scala compiler." Java does not have a concept corresponding to Scala `type`s.

Comment: I'm after a potential solution to pass type L0 to the `Holder`, with or without using type aliases that are callable from Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained elsewhere, Java doesn't have `type`s in the sense that Scala does.

If you need Java interop (with respect to the concrete type used in `Holder`), sticking to type parameters might work for you:

```
trait Holder[LType] {
  type L = LType
}

object Holder extends Holder[L0]
```

Expanding on this for a bit, if L0 is `String`, you could do:

```
trait IHolder[LType] {
  type L = LType
  def l: LType
}

object Holder extends IHolder[String] {
  override val l: L = "foo" //this typechecks
}
```

Then, from Java, you can do:

```
IHolder<String> holder = Holder$.MODULE$;
String foo = holder.l();

//or, skipping IHolder:
String foo = Holder.l();
```

Note that I renamed the `trait` so that calling `Holder.l()` from Java code unambiguously refers to the `object`.